# Elastic Beanstalk Can't Deploy my ASP Net Core application on Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a basic ASP Net Core application, developed on Windows, which I'm trying to deploy into an Elastic Beanstalk linux environment.

When I deploy, I get the following error:

```
2020/12/02 23:47:10.550207 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command
[app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command.
Error: there is no .runtimeconfig.json file for your single application. 
Please provide a valid application
```

The problem is, there **is** a *.runtimeconfig.json file in my deployed .zip file!

The structure of my zip file is loosly:

```
./Config/configs.xml
./Config/secrets.xml
...tons of .dll & .so files
PublicWeb.dll
PublicWeb.runtimeconfig.json
```

So I'm mystified as to what the problem is.

Comment: The files are directly under the zip yet? One issue I often get into when deploying with zip for AWS is that there is a "appname" folder before the actual root source structure inside the zip file like this my-app.zip > my-app > my-app.dll

Comment: Nope, all files right at the zip root

Comment: Upload the blank application somewhere, I'll try it out and see if I can't make it work, either

Comment: Thanks @qkhanhpro, but I finally figured it out!  Details posted below.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally fixed it, by following these steps:

1. I was on .NET 2.1; so I upgraded to .NET 3.1 by following the migration guide.
2. I created a Debian image on WSL 2, git cloned my repo into it
3. Then I ran dotnet deploy from here & uploaded this artifact.

I'll note that the zip artifact was much smaller when built on linux for linux.